# How can one prove the ownership of an address?

Tags: address, message-signing, ownership

Is there a way to prove the ownership of an address without spending bitcoins? I Imagine something like signing some given data with the private key - how much would that weaken the security of the bitcoins behind the Address? Any good read on this topic is welcome!

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3898/how-does-sign-message-work

Comment: tanks - was missing the right keyword - now I have them

Comment: Removed a comment here, because using a spoofed link to refer to lmgtfy is rude. Please rather ask, whether OP has tried looking for "correct keyword", or just flag it as the corresponding duplicate.